# how to get url's dynamic title http://localhost:4300/title/örange which contain ö

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, frontend

I am getting data from backend using URL
and my URL is

```
http://localhost:4300/title/örange
```

the title of blog i am showing in URL
and one of my user give title like this => my-örange
and when i am fetching title from URL i am getting title as my-%C3%B6range
i am getting title in react as this

```js
let { title } = this.props.match.params;
console.log(title) // output => my-%C3%B6rang
//i want output my-örange
```

so how to get same string?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `decodeURIComponent()`. Read more on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). Example:

```
let { title } = decodeURIComponent(this.props.match.params);
console.log(title) // output => my-örange
```

Comment: Just small addition. If you use Functional Components and React Router you can try useParams hook from 'react-router' instead of match;

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-router useParams instead (from version v5.1):

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
const params = useParams()
console.log(params.title)
```

the route:

```
 <Route path="blog/:title" element={<Blog />} />
```

and the URL should be http://localhost:4300/blog/örange